# SQL Where clause equivalent for Elastic Search

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, lucene, dsl, equivalent

I am trying to create a aggregate results in elastic search but filter option is not working for me.

I can aggregate data without filter e.g.

```
select  name , material ,sum(price)
from products group by name , material 

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty=true' -d' 
{
    "aggs" : {
        "product" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "name"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "material" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "field" : "material"
                    },
                    "aggs" : {
                        "sum_price" : {
                            "sum" : {
                                "field" : "price"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}'
```

but I am facing problems to write equivalent DSL query of :

```
select  name , material ,sum(price)
from products 
where material = "wood"
group by name , material
```

Comment: Add `query` clause to your request with term query inside it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "material": "wood"
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "aggs" : {
        "product" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "name"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "material" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "field" : "material"
                    },
                    "aggs" : {
                        "sum_price" : {
                            "sum" : {
                                "field" : "price"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}
```

Use a filter if you know the exact value and do not need a match, else use a match query instead of the filtered query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **match**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {            
          "match": {
            "material": "wood"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
      ]
    }  
  },
    "aggs" : {
        "product" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "name"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "material" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "field" : "material"
                    },
                    "aggs" : {
                        "sum_price" : {
                            "sum" : {
                                "field" : "price"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}
```